# get top position of the web page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to take position of the top (window top x=0 and y=0) visible part of the web page.

Please see this image

[image]

Comment: You have enough reputation to put your code. why dont you share that.

Comment: @milind anantwar whole need content here. no need codes for this. thank you!

Comment: are you sure you are not asking for the top y position?

Comment: Brain... Brain... More bugs than in computer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need:

```
 $(window).scrollTop();
```

Using Javascript:

```
 document.documentElement.scrollTop  ||  window.pageYOffset
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F7z4f/5/)**

Comment: What is the confusion??

Comment: Coz it JQuery, not js

Comment: You tagged the question with jquery tag. see the update above. have js code now.

Answer (score 2):

**Common:**

```
var X - $(window).screenX();
var Y - $(window).screenY();
```

**IE:**

```
var X = $(window).screenLeft();
var Y - $(window).screenTop();
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: its really helps me hope others too!